# window.removeEventListener is not working in Nuxt JS

Tags: nuxt.js, event-listener, removeeventlistener

I have declared **scroll** event listener in the created hook.

```js
created () {
        if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
            window.addEventListener('scroll', this.handleNavScroll);
        }
},
```

But when I am moving to another url at that time I am trying to destroy this event listener at beforeDestroy() hook but it's not working.

```js
beforeDestroy() {
        console.log('before destroy called ...');
        window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.handleNavScroll)
}
```

Even I have tried to destroy it from destroyed () hook also but not working and not removing it.

```js
destroyed () {
        console.log('destroyed called in home page');
        window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.handleNavScroll)
}
```

This is my method

```js
handleNavScroll() {
        this.scrolled = window.scrollY > 0;

        if(window.scrollY > 150){
            this.navColor = false;
            this.$root.$emit('navbarColorProps', 'black')
            this.$root.$emit('navbarColorMobileProps', 'black')
        }
        if(window.scrollY < 150){
            this.navColor = true;
            this.$root.$emit('navbarColorProps', 'rgba(255,255,255,0.0) !important')
            this.$root.$emit('navbarColorMobileProps', 'rgba(255,255,255,0.0) !important')
        }

}
```

Please help me can not able to remove the event listener.